# Why I'm getting only one post with get_posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

**UPDATE: I now know why didn't worked. It was because I was trying to show a private post. Dumm me. Happens to the best of us. Sorry. And thanks for all your help.**

I'm trying to list all posts with certain meta key and meta value but I can't get all the posts with that certain meta value. I'm only getting one.

I have a foreach loop and the next code to list all my posts like this:

```php
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'produs', 
        'meta_key' => 'sticky_post', 
        'meta_value' => 1
); 
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

```html
          <?php
       foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
                                <div class="product" id="product-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                                    <div class="thumb new_product_thumb">
                                    <?php 

                                        $thumb_args = array('class' => 'product-img', 'alt' => the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); 

                                        ?>

                                    <a class="product-thumb read-more" style="" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" title="citește mai departe">

                                        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('product-listing', $thumb_args); ?>

                                    </a>
                                     <?php  //if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
                                                if (get_field('tva_produs',$post->ID) == '9') echo '<div class="tva_redus"></div>';
                                                // var_dump($top_sellers_new);
                                            //}
                                     ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <h2>

                                        <a class="read-more" style="" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" title="citește mai departe">

                                            <?php the_title(); ?>

                                        </a>

                                    </h2>

                                    <div class="product-content">

                                        Pret: <?php echo get_field('pret_nou', $post->ID); ?> lei

                                    </div>

                                    <a class="read-more more2" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" title="citește mai departe"><p>Detalii produs</p> <span class="arrow-next">&nbsp;</span></a>

                                    <?php $id = get_the_ID();?>

                                    <form id="adauga_in_cos" action="<?php echo THEME_URL; ?>/product.php?action=add&product=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="produs_id" id="produs_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

                                        <input type="hidden" name="produs_price" id="produs_price" value="<?php echo get_field( 'pret_nou', $id ) ?>" />

                                        <input type="hidden" name="produs_name" id="produs_name" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" />

                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="add_to_sc" id="add-<?php echo $id; ?>"></a>

                                    <!-- <input id="adauga_but" class="add_to_sc" type="submit" value="Adauga in cos" />-->

                                    </form>

                                    <div class="horizontal"></div>

                                </div>

                         <?php } ?>
```

Why do I get only one post with meta_value 1, instead of all with meta_value 1 ?

Comment: @lonut can u please provide full code with foreach loop

Comment: @Weblineindia, it's kind of alot of code in the foreach. The main thing is even when I do a var_dump($posts), I'm getting an array of 1 element.

Comment: I've updated the code with the foreach loop too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues here

- Do not abuse the the `$posts` global, you are using it as a custom variable, so you are breaking the global. Use a custom variable name, something like `$posts_array.
- If you are going to use `$post`, (*which you should use to setup postadat*), you should reset it back to its original value
- Set `posts_per_page` to `-1` to get all posts with the desired custom field

Your code should look something like this: (*Untested*)

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'produs', 
    'meta_key' => 'sticky_post', 
    'meta_value' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
); 
$posts_array = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // All your other code

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If this does not work, you should make sure of that you do not have a bad instance of the `pre_get_posts` action

Comment: There there is a bad filter

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding

```
'numberposts'       => -1,
```

This should make get_post get all the posts available, if that doesn't work we can't help you further unless you provide more code

Comment: I've already tried that. Doesn't work. Updated the question with the foreach loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can use **posts_per_page** argument, and set it -1

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Have you looked at my $args above. Your answer doesn't help at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That was just an example, which i quoted above. You will have to invest your time in modifying it as per your requirement. Look at the above answer. I mentioned to use posts_per_page argument additionally, Apart from that your default arguments can be in there.

Answer (score 0):

'meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect).

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'produs', 
        'meta_key' => 'sticky_post', 
        'meta_value' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
); 
$myposts = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Same thing happening. Returns only one post.

Comment: My answer now updat please try @Ionut

Comment: My answer now updat please try @Ionut

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use WP_Query  rather than get_posts

If you only need an array of posts, and don't need the query object -use get_posts(). Otherwise, if you do need the access to the query object methods, or pagination, or sticky posts at the top, you should use WP_Query.

Normally (by default with WP_Query object) - WordPress queries how many posts there are in total - even if you are only after the first 10. It does this so it can perform pagination. So get_posts() is actually (slightly) quicker (it also ignores sticky posts).

Comment: WP_Query returns all the posts instead of taking in account the $args. Also I'm not using sticky posts. I've made my own custom sticky posts with ACF. I have two radio buttons which makes my posts "sticky".

Comment: It can search the custom fields too , so the same query will work for the wp_query too

Comment: Did you had any luck on this?